# How does laravel know the unread notifications i not see any difference in the notifications table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am unable to determine if a notification has been read or not. I have checked the notifications table for ones that I have viewed, and the `read_at` value is `null`.

I have tried to access unread notifications with the following code:

```
return Auth::user()->unreadNotifications;
```

How does Laravel indicate a notification has been read and what are possible causes for the notifications table or model instances to not be updated?

Comment: Does your user model have the `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait?

Comment: Rewrote question (per my understanding of it) as it was very unclear. Added additional relevant tags for visibility.

Comment: you should use the `markAsRead()` method or manually update the column once user view the notification. Checkout the docs, it' there https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications